# Calling two functions onsubmit of a form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, client-side, jquery-events, client-side-validation

I am using client_side_validations gem in a rails application for form validation, it adds some functions for form on submit that does the validation, I need to perform a custom validation on my own that is outside of the functionality of the client_side_validations gem, so when I add it using `form.submit = function` it works, both validations are called. but it I don't understand how will the decision to either submit the form or not submit it will be made, if both functions return false then it should submit but it looks like even if one of them returns true the form is submitted without waiting for the other to return its value, How can I handle such a case, I cannot make it into one function because that will mean putting in my code inside the client_side_validations JavaScript file, which I would never want to do?

Any ideas and help is appreciated.

Here is my custom validation code for reference:

```
 $('#new_business').submit ->
    that = $('#business_referrer_code')
    if(that.attr("validated") == "true")
      return true
    else
      code = $('#business_referrer_code')
      $.ajax '/representatives/validate_code',
        type: 'GET'
        dataType: 'json'
        data: "code=#{code.val()}"
        success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
          if(data.error)
            that.after("<label class='message'> Invalid Reference Code</label>")
          else
            that.attr("validated", true)
            that.submit()
      false
    true
```

The other code the is auto generated by client_side_validations is something I cannot change.

Comment: added code for reference

Comment: You will probably have to not use the .submit and instead use onclick.  Based on the results call submit

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution you could try:

```
onsubmit="return validateName() && validatePhone() && validateAddress() && validateEmail()"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using some client side parameters you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkValues()
    {
        var value1 = functionGetValue1Value();
        var value2 = functionGetValue2Value();

        if (value1 == True && value2 == True)
        {
            completeSubmit();
        }
    }

    function completeSubmit()
    {
        // create a (post) request to some destination.
    }
</script>
<form action="javascript:checkValues();">
    <submit value="submit" />
</form>
```

You can also pass the client side variables (?) to the server and check them on the server.

If you do this than it's possible someone sniffing on the network can take these variables and hijack the session or something like that. But it's better than pure client side verification where users can edit the js code and pass thru.

Comment: as I said I cannot take and put the two functions together in one. and I have my validations on my backend server so no worries about by passing the js code.